# Proving that the solution of $x_{n+1}=\sqrt[3]{x_n+x_{n-1}}$ must satisfy $x=\sqrt[3]{x+x}$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I had a question that was to compute the limit of the sequence $$x_0=3, x_1=2, x_{n+1}=\sqrt[3]{x_n+x_{n-1}}$$. First, I showed that the sequence is decreasing and has lower bound 1, so it has a limit. Then I said that if $x$ is the limit then it satisfies the equality $x=\sqrt[3]{x+x}$ so the solutions are $x=0,-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}$. I understand intuitively that the limit $x$ must satisfy $x=\sqrt[3]{x+x}$ but how can I prove it rigorously?

Comment: The cube root function is continuous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if $x_n\to x$ then also $x_{n+1}\to x$. Also $x_{n-1}\to x$ and  thus$\sqrt[3]{x_n+x_{n-1}} \to \sqrt[3]{x+x}$, since $x\mapsto \sqrt[3]{x}$ is continuous.

Comment: I see. Thanks !

Comment: you are welcome